# Call Child Method from Parent with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, methods, parent-child

I know that this is a pretty common question but some answers I found on the internet are deprecated.
How do you call a method of a Child Component from the Parent Component in 2020?
My actual code is something like this but it's not working

Child:

```
export default class CustomComp extends React.Component{
  exampleMethod = () => {
    console.log('pressed');
  };

  render(){
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  child = CustomComp;
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Press" onPress={this.child.exampleMethod} />
        <CustomComp ref={child => {this.child = child}} {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can follow in this example. Here I used `React.createRef` and pass the ref into child and then I called `this.child.current.getAlert`

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";

export default class MyParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.child.current.getAlert('Mr. Kamal');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={this.child} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    getAlert(name) {
        alert(`Hi ${name}`);
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>Hello</h1>;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the difference between my way and this way? (except mine is not working)

Comment: you set your component to another var like `child = CustomComp` but React gets the reference of any component using `React.createRef()` and that ref could be used to access of property of that child compoent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function as a callback function.

```
onPress={() => this.child.exampleMethod()}
```

Plus, I think `child = CustomComp` has no effect since `ref={child => {this.child = child}}` is NOT affected by `child = CustomComp`.

So, your `Parent` js file should be as follows.

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Press" onPress={() => this.child.exampleMethod()} />
        <CustomComp ref={child => {this.child = child}} {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```